# LWC - How do we display an independent row inside the data table in Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm new with programming and I would appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction or provide suggestions with this issue I'm having. I currently have a Data Table and my foreach rows are correctly displaying. I do however, would like to display a *separate* row for adding new lines.

Image shown below:

[image]

Would it be possible to add an independent row *inside* in the data table? The problem is whenever I add content, it shows only as text and messes up the layout. I'm just trying to add a button with a very short label in.

Here's what I have:

**Mark-Up**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Mass Edit on Products">
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium slds-scrollable" style="height:300px;">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered" >
                <thead>
                    <tr class="">
                        <th class="slds-size_1-of-8" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Product Name">PRODUCT</div>
                        </th>

                        <!-- ... MORE CODES HERE ... -->

                        <th class="slds-size_1-of-8" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Amount">AMOUNT</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-size_1-of-8" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Action"></div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template for:each = {myList} for:item = "item" for:index="indexVar">
                    <tr key={item.key} class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td class="slds-size_3-of-10" data-label="Product">
                            <div  title="">
                                <template if:false={isEdited} if:true={item.Product__c}> 
                                    <lightning-formatted-url value={item.ProductUrl} label={item.ProductName} target="_self"></lightning-formatted-url>
                                </template>
                                <template if:true={isEdited}>

                        <!-- ... MORE CODES HERE ... -->

                        <td class="slds-size_1-of-10" data-label="Remove">
                            <a name={indexVar} data-id={item.Id} onclick={remove}>
                                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:delete" alternative-text="delete"  size="small"></lightning-icon>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                        
                </template>

            <!-- THIS IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO INSERT THE ACTION -->

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to insert the following:

```
<lightning-layout> 
     <lightning-button-icon label="Add Product" slot="actions" onclick={add}></lightning-button-icon>
</lightning-layout>
```

Any suggestion would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You can have an empty row with the same structure in a template, parallel to the template containing your for each loop. And either on the button click or on changing of the data you can save it on backend and again make that spare row empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simply add the surrounding HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <lightning-button-icon label="Add Product" slot="actions" onclick={add}> 
    </lightning-button-icon>
  </td>
</tr>
```